# java will intermittently not resolve symlinks on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, java

I'm trying to resolve canonical paths for all the files in a folder tree, but for some reason it will not resolve them (and intermittently the JVM security code will resolve the symlink properly within the FilePermission and cause a security error).

Env:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

A known symlink in the system is /usr/share/java/gnome-java-bridge.jar:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 2012-02-24 13:39 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar -> ../../../../../../share/java/gnome-java-bridge.jar
```

The following code should resolve this known symlink:

```
String symlinkedFilePath =
    "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar";

File symlinkedFile = new File(symlinkedFilePath);

System.out.println(symlinkedFile.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(symlinkedFile.getCanonicalPath());
```

but produces:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar
```

A further test, using the following code, will sometimes return true for the permission check, but sometimes will return false:

```
String symlinkedFilePath =
    "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar";

File symlinkedFile = new File(symlinkedFilePath);

FilePermission recursivePermission = new FilePermission(
    symlinkedFile.getParentFile().getParent() + "/-", "read");

FilePermission filePermission = new FilePermission(
    symlinkedFile.getAbsolutePath(), "read");

System.out.println(recursivePermission);
System.out.println(filePermission);
System.out.println(
    "Can read symlink: " + recursivePermission.implies(filePermission));
```

The typical result is:

```
(java.io.FilePermission /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/- read)
(java.io.FilePermission /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar read)
Can read symlink: true
```

but when debugging, if I step through the creation of the FilePermission on the target file, internally the path is resolved to the symlink, and the output results in:

```
(java.io.FilePermission /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/- read)
(java.io.FilePermission /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar read)
Can read symlink: false
```

The problem is that within the context of the app in which the permission checking actually takes place, the symlink is always resolved by the FilePermission object, but never by my own calls to file.getCanonicalPath() as demonstrated above.

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: You may wish to file a bug report; I cannot reproduce the initial `getCanonicalPath()` problem with either the openjdk or the sun jdk on my Ubuntu 11.04 system.

Comment: sarnold, are you using the exact OpenJDK version? Wonder if perhaps it's an issue in the specific release. furthermore, I just discovered that I can get the canonical paths to resolve 100% of the time if I set either -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false or -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false but that seems odd.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think to include version numbers; `java -version` reports `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)` `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)`.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a diffrence but try to  run your application as root .

Comment: An obscure long shot: does it make any difference if the symlink is amended to target an 'absolute' path? (i.e. `/usr/share/java/gnome-java-bridge.jar`)

Comment: I would not rely on any OpenJDK 6 release wherever it comes from. Let's have a try with OpenJDK 7 !

Comment: Hello all, thank you for the feedback. A colleague of mine confirmed the issue on OpenJDK 6u23, but not on any prior or following versions. That being said, since the issue has A) a work around in the form of the system property, and B) appears to be resolved in the later build (u24), there appears to be little motivation to dig any deeper. Should I use this as the answer to my own question?

Comment: I don't think anyone would complain against that Ray.

Comment: Perhaps you should try Java 7 which has support for symlinks. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html.

Comment: In this particular case we can't rely on JDK7 since we're a product company and we must support Java 6. This supports our extensive deployment matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colleague of mine confirmed the issue on OpenJDK 6u23, but not on any prior or following versions. That being said, since the issue has

A) a work around in the form of the system property

```
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false 
OR
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
```

B) appears to be resolved in the later build (u24)

there appears to be little motivation to dig any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix a symlink is a "special" file, with its own permissions.

The fact that you have read permission on the symbolic link doesn't imply you'll have it for the file linked.

My guess here is that you are running your program as an user that can read the symlink but not the actual file.

When entering debug mode you trigger the call to some method that change the internal state of the FilePermission object making it resolve to the actual file and thus returning you "false".

When you get "true" it's just telling you that you can read the symbolic link.

In your place, I'll check permission on this file:
 - /usr/share/java/gnome-java-bridge.jar

and to the two directories:
 - /usr/share
 - /usr/share/java

Comment: Both the file and the symlink have "read" for "other" so this seems not to be the issue, as do the directories in the hierarchy.